# Can we use any specific design pattern here?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I currently have some functionality like following in my method.

```
if(obj instanceof A) {
            someString = ((ChildClass)((A)obj)).get(0).getSomeString();

        }
if(obj instanceof B) {
            someString = ((B)obj)).getSomeString();
        }
if(obj instanceof C) {
            someString = ((c)obj)).getSomeString();
        }

        someString = performSomeOperation(someString);

if(obj instanceof A) {
            ((ChildClass)((A)obj)).get(0).setSomeString(someString);
        }
if(obj instanceof B) {
            someString = ((B)obj)).setSomeString(someString);
        }
if(obj instanceof C) {
            someString = ((c)obj)).setSomeString(someString);
        }
```

I am advised to use builder pattern, but I am not sure if we can use builder pattern here, is it possible? if not, is there any other approach?

Comment: Any specific reason for down-vote? I would like to know how I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

use an `interface` or maybe `abstract class`. Eg:

```
public interface IObj 
{
    public String getSomething();
}
```

```
public class AA implements IObj {

String name="";
public AA(String s)
{
    name=s;
}
@Override
public String getSomething()
{
    return "AA:"+name;
}
}
```

```
public class BB implements IObj {

String name="";
public BB(String s)
{
    name=s;
}
@Override
public String getSomething()
{
    return "BB:"+name;
}
}
```

```
public class ABTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IObj iobj = new AA("msg A");
    System.out.println(iobj.getSomething());
    iobj = new BB("msg B");
    System.out.println(iobj.getSomething());
}
}
```

Output:

`AA:msg A`

`BB:msg B`